# what should be the parametric form of the l2 regularization in a Bayesian setting?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian

In a Bayesian setting for parameter estimation, what should be the parametric form of the prior distribution in order to perform l2 regularization?

Comment: L2 regularization has a Bayesian interpretation under certain assumptions. Is that what you mean by "in the Bayesian setting"?

Comment: Could you be more specific when you mentioned 'bayesian' setting. Is this a exam question?

Comment: @jerad Yes, I want to know the form of L2 regularization's   Bayesian interpretation.

Comment: @ImWatchingYou. No, not an exam question :)

Answer (score 3):

L2 regularization is generally equivalent to a Gaussian prior. See, for example, Jason Rennie's [On L2-norm Regularization and the Gaussian Prior](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.113.1049) (2003).

(For future reference: don't [cross-post your questions to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315370/what-should-be-the-parametric-form-of-the-l2-regularization-in-a-bayesian-settin/15316902#15316902); this is the right place for questions like this.)